# write text into ploygon with PDFBox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I found out how to write text onto the page with drawText and the polygon appears at the right place with drawPolygon.

The issue is that when I just draw text it works but as soon as I draw the polygons, the text is not drawn anymore.

If I create two PDPageContentStream objects (one for the text and another for the polygon) the polygons are not drawn anymore.

Here is my test class. Any PDF should do for testing.

```
    package ch.sertal.vision.server.helpers;

import ch.sertal.vision.BaseDaoTest;
import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: micha.roon
 * Date: 11/13/11
 * Time: 11:22 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class WritePDFTest extends BaseDaoTest {

   @Test
   public void testTextPlacement() throws IOException, COSVisitorException, URISyntaxException {
      File pdfFile = new File( this.getClass().getResource( "/META-INF/menge-regierapport.pdf" ).toURI() );
      PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load( pdfFile );
      PDPage page = null;
      for ( Object kid : doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().getKids() ) {
         if ( kid instanceof PDPage ) {
            page = ( PDPage ) kid;
            break;
         }
      }
      PDPageContentStream rectContent = new PDPageContentStream( doc, page, true, false );
      rectContent.setNonStrokingColor( Color.blue );

      PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream( doc, page, true, false );

      writeOnPage( content, String.valueOf( page.getArtBox().getHeight() ), 0, 0 );
      writeOnPage( content, String.valueOf( page.getArtBox().getWidth() ), 200, 100 );
      rectContent.fillRect( 100, 200, 100, 50 );
      content.close();
      doc.save( new FileOutputStream(
                  new File( this.getClass().getResource( "/META-INF/menge-regierapport.pdf" ).toURI() )) );
      doc.close();
   }

   void writeOnPage(PDPageContentStream content, String text, int x, int y) throws IOException {
      content.beginText();
      content.setFont( PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 10 );
      content.moveTextPositionByAmount( x, y );
      content.drawString( text );
      content.endText();
   }

}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You don't seem to close 'rectContent'.

Answer (score 1):

1. your main issue is that you never call `rectContent.close()`.
2. It appears that `rectContent` and `content` are actually pointers to the same "stream" and it may make sense to rework the code to address how PDFBox is actually working.  This would mean (a) removing `rectContent` and replacing it with `content`.

   ```
   PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream( doc, page, true, false );
   content.setNonStrokingColor( Color.blue );

   // moving this before content, so it's written "below" (I think)
   content.fillRect( 100, 200, 100, 50 );

   // resetting the color to black
   content.setNonStrokingColor( Color.black );

   writeOnPage( content, String.valueOf( page.getArtBox().getHeight() ), 0, 0 );
   writeOnPage( content, String.valueOf( page.getArtBox().getWidth() ), 200, 100 );
   content.close();
   doc.save( new FileOutputStream(
         new File( this.getClass().getResource( "/META-INF/menge-regierapport.pdf" ).toURI() )) );
   doc.close();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `setNonStrokingColor` is the same when you draw the Rect and the text. So the Rect will hide the text. The solution is to call `setNonStrokingColor` with different values for the Rect and the text. Then you should be able to see both of them.